# How do I define object data type in parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, adonis.js

My code like this :

```
public async index(params: any) {
    return params
}
```

return params like this :

```
{
    "data": {
        "params": {
            "task_id": 101
        }
    }
}
```

I want to define object data type in parameter. So it does not use `any`

I try like this :

```
public async index(params: object) {
    return params
}
```

But there exist message : `Property 'params' does not exist on type 'object'`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `params: { data: { params: { task_id: number } } }` assuming, of course, this is typescript.

Comment: @briosheje yeah, this is typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by defining an own type that fits your object. In your example, this would be:

```
type paramsType = {
   data: {
      params: {
         task_id: number
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can write (params: paramsType). Let me know if this works. :)

Comment: my parameters are many and varied. that would define a lot

Comment: Yeah thats true, but that is actually quite common in TypeScript as far as I know. You can alter exisiting type tho. Check this link for reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: Okay thanks. Btw define type outside class? right?

Comment: You should be able to do it outside the class

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
type myParamsType = {
   data: {
      params: {
         task_id: number
      }
   }
}

public async index(params: myParamsType) {
    return params;
}

// Use like this.

myParams: myParamsType = {
    "data": {
        "params": {
            "task_id": 101
        }
    }
};

let params = index(myParams);
```

You can also define a class instead of a type. Depends of what you have to do with datas.

Comment: define type outside class? right?

Comment: @positivedeveloper Yes outside class. `type` is an alias for `interface`